# Using node-config package, is there a way to set custom-environment-variables.json in javascript?

Tags: vercel, node-config

I'm having issues deploying to Now with `node-config` custom env vars.

Now does not deploy my `custom-environment-variables.json` file, but I am able to import it and print it to the console. Is there a way to pass this object to `node-config` so it makes use of the env vars I have specified?

Comment: I don't know much about `node-config`, but if you need to set environment variables, you can add them to your `now.json` file. Any secrets such as passwords should use `now secrets`. See the docs here: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/environment-variables-and-secrets

Answer (score 0):

So for my specific question there isn't a way to do it. This is the code relating to it:
https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/blob/master/lib/config.js#L1216

To deploy with Now v2 there may be a solution. Still searching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a maintainer of `node-config`. The `custom-environment-variables.json` file should be deployed and the environment variables mentioned in there should be set in the environment before `node-config` is loaded.

Comment: Appreciate the response Mark. Not sure how much that helps getting things working with Now v2 though? For now I've stopped using now however.